# pyqt graphicsitem mouse enter event

Tags: events, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to connect to the mouse-enter event of QGraphicsItems that are placed onto a QGraphicsScene and visualized through a QGraphicsView. From what I understand, the method to override for this is dragEnterEvent in a class derived from QGraphicsItem (or one of it's subclasses). My attempt looks like this:

```
class StaPoly(QtGui.QGraphicsPolygonItem):

    def __init__(self,*args):
        QtGui.QGraphicsPolygonItem.__init__(self,*args)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self,event):
        print "Enter!"        

...

    def draw(self):        
        p       = self.parent

        self.group = QtGui.QGraphicsItemGroup(scene=p.scene)

...

        for xpix in lons: 
            poly = QtGui.QPolygonF()
            poly << QtCore.QPointF(xpix-symw,ypix)
            poly << QtCore.QPointF(xpix,ypix+symh)                
            poly << QtCore.QPointF(xpix+symw,ypix)                
            poly << QtCore.QPointF(xpix,ypix-symh)                                                

            item = StaPoly(poly)
            item.setPen(QtGui.QColor(color))
            item.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))  
            self.group.addToGroup(item)
```

I hope the above snippets make it clear what I am trying to do. Note that the display is generated exactly as I desire, no issue there - however the polygons that get drawn are not responding to the enter-event - I am not seeing any evidence that dragEnterEvent() is being called.

Comment: are you overloading other mouse routines ? like mouseMove ? make sure to call the super class if you the mouse event is not relevant for any action.

Comment: @fabrizioM: not in StaPoly, no. I am however overriding mouseMove in my GraphicsView-derived class, and I have already tested disabling that function but it makes no difference. Do I need to be overloading mouseMove in my GraphicsItem class for the other stuff to work?

Comment: did you put self.setAcceptDrops(True), inside the GraphicsView ?

Comment: @fabrizioM: No, as the events I had on the graphicsview worked fine. I will try that though and see what happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (partial) solution was this:

```
self.group.setHandlesChildEvents(False)
```

This ensures that individual items handle their own events, it seems that before the group was capturing them.

I still have a problem in that my GraphicsView overrides the mouseMoveEvent, and when enabled, no events get propagated to scene items.

EDIT: And it seems the solution to this second problem was to call the base class mouseMoveEvent handler from the Views mouseMoveEvent handler e.g.

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
    QtGui.QGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)
```